# Send Cart::content to the blade in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm using
 "bumbummen99/shoppingcart": "^2.8",
In laravel 5.8
Help me to send my cart::content to the blade template.

```html
//ShoppingController.php
Mail::send('emails.ordermail-customer-response',
       array(
            'cartcontent' => Cart::content()
), function($message) use ($request)
```

When I'm sending Cart::content to the e-mail blade template, everything works great

```html
 @foreach ($cartcontent as $item)
 
 {{$item->name}}
 
 {{$item->price}}
 
 @endforeach
```

But when I'm saving cart content to my database like this

```html
///shoppingcontroller.php

$order = Orders::create([

            'cartcontent' => Cart::content()
 ]);
```

In my database I have a string

```html
{"76074528274137cc4af420551cfac36a":{"rowId":"76074528274137cc4af420551cfac36a",
"id":9,"name":"product","qty":"1",
"price":382,"weight":0,"options":{"color":"black","variant":null,"deliveryprice":"40",
"qtyinOnePocket":"1"},
"discount":0,"tax":0,"subtotal":382}}
```

Than I' trying to send the data from database to my blade template

```html
//shoppingcontroller.php

public function showSingleOrder($orderId)
    {

        $order = Orders::find($orderId);

        return view('admin.sections.orders.ordersingle')
        ->with('order', $order);

    }
```

And here is my blade

```html
////ordersingle.blade.php

{{$order->cartcontent}}
```

Gives me this

```html
{"76074528274137cc4af420551cfac36a":{"rowId":"76074528274137cc4af420551cfac36a",
"id":9,"name":"product","qty":"1",
"price":382,"weight":0,"options":{"color":"black","variant":null,"deliveryprice":"40",
"qtyinOnePocket":"1"},
"discount":0,"tax":0,"subtotal":382}}
```

But when I'm using foreach in my blade like this

```html
//ordersingle.blade

@foreach($order->cartcontent as $item)
      {{$item->price}}
@endforeach
```

I don't recieve the price but an error

```html
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: `$order->cartcontent` is a JSON string; you can't use it in a `@foreach()` loop without converting it to something that PHP can iterate over.

Comment: check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/convert-json-to-eloquent-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) to your *orders* model. It'll transform the JSON saved in the `cartcontent` column back into an array using `json_decode()`.

**Orders.php**

```
class Orders extends Model {
    // ...

    protected $casts = [
        'cartcontent' => 'array',
    ];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it tomorrow.